# Center the first widget in a row in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I would like to center the `FirstWidget` in a row in flutter, not the complete row. The second widget should follow right next to it.

````
{
return Container(
           child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              FirstWidget(...),
              
              SecondWidget(...),            ],
          ));
}
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the other widgets have the same width, we could use the `Spacer` widget to fill the space, as per the following code:

```
Row(
   children: [
      FirstWidget(),
      Spacer(),
      CenteredWidget(),
      Spacer(),
      SecondWidget(),
   ]
)
```

Another solution would be to wrap the `Row` in a `Stack` and use the power of `Positioned` to overlay a `Widget` in the center:

```
Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: [
        FirstWidget(),
        Row(children: _rowChildren),
    ],
)
```

Comment: the first widget should be centered. the size of the widget should not matter.

Comment: Is using a `Stack` as a wrapper an option? If so, I've added another solution to the answer.

Comment: Stack does not work either because the second widget should follow right after the first. With a stack, the two widgets are not really related anymore.